# Workout the most efficient location for hospitals in a country

Tags: geolocation, statistics, location

I have a problem. If I had a country with a *pre-defined* distribution of people, each with different health problems - how could I work out the ideal location for hospitals in the country?

If I downloaded a map, roughly showing the location of everyone in a country, how would I calculate the best location for let's say... 30 hospitals? How would I work out the hospital locations, so every person has to take the shortest route to their nearest hospital. *Obviously compromising, as not everyone would be able to follow the most efficient route.*

I'm not entirely sure how to approach this programming wise. Or even which languages to use. Should I use a low-level language, like Java or maybe access the map data with Python? And i'm guessing it would take my humble PC quite a while to calculate such a problem. Anyway, your ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in combinatorial optimization, which is a vast and rich field of study. My advice is to put aside programming questions for now, and try to understand the problem better first. My guess is that an exact solution would be very time-consuming to find, and that you will need a heuristic search of some kind. But an exact solution, perhaps through direct enumeration (i.e. brute force), is very useful to compare to proposed heuristics (in order to verify that the heuristics are working as you expect).

As to heuristics, maybe construct Voronoi cells containing equal number of people and then find the best location within each cell. Good luck and have fun.